# Optimizing a set 20 webrequests with threads

Tags: asp.net, multithreading

This is for ASP.NET. I want to improve the time it takes run my function, today it takes around 20-30 seconds, more towards 30secs than 20secs though. That's running on one thread making 20 webrequests.

I'm thinking threads that do all the 20 webreqeusts, in order to quickly find the result or just go through the data (IE do all the 20 requests not finding anything).

**Here's how it works.**
1. I'm using html agility pack to fetch htmldocuments.
 2. Then I parse them for information
 3. Lastly I add that information to a dictionary **OR** I move on to the next webrequest until I reach 20 requests made.

I make at most 20 webRequests, at minimum 1. I have set the function to end when the info I'm searching for is found. Sometimes the info isn't there hence the 20 webrequests(it goes through all the data).

Every webrequest adds between 5-20 entries to the dictionary. This is then compared with the information I sent to it, if it's in the list I get the Key back, otherwise it returns 201. If found it gets added to the database.

**QUESTIONS**

*A:*If I want to do this with threads, how many should I create? 20 One for each request and let them all loose to do the job? Or should i create like 4 of them making at most 5 requests each?
*B:* What if two threads are finished at the same time and wants to add info to the directory, can it lock the whole site(I'm using ASP.NET), or will it try to add one from thread A and then one result from Thread B? I have a check already today that checks if the key exists before adding it.

**C:What would be the fastest way to this?**

This is my code, depicting the loop which just shows that 20 requests are being made?

```
public void FetchAndParseAllPages()
    {

        int _maxSearchDepth = 200;
        int _searchIncrement = 10;

        PageFetcher fetcher = new PageFetcher();
        for (int i = 0; i < _maxSearchDepth; i += _searchIncrement)
        {
            string keywordNsearch = _keyword + i;
            ParseHtmldocuments(fetcher.GetWebpage(keywordNsearch));

            if (GetPostion() != 201)
            {   //ADD DATA TO DATABASE
                InsertRankingData(DocParser.GetSearchResults(), _theSearchedKeyword);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. .NET allows only 2 requests open at the same time. If you want more than that, you need to configure it in web.config. Look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480507.aspx
2. You can the `Parallel.For` method which is very straightforward and handles the "how much threads" for you. Of course you can tweak it to set how much threads (or tasks) you want with `ParallelOptions`. Look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd781401.aspx
3. For making a thread-safe dictionary you can use the `ConcurrentDictionary`. Look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx

Comment: Seems like the asynchronous PreRequestHandler approach is the best one? But I haven't really look into that, do you have any examples? Can I use that solution for my application? Bear in mind I use htmlweb.PreRequest = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.PreRequestHandler(OnPreRequest); when i connect to to fetch the webpage.

Comment: "handles the "how much threads" for you." This is only true for CPU-bound work. For IO-bound work the heuristics go catastrophically wrong.